# error handling batch Apex

Tags: apex, error-messages

What would be a better way of error handling in batch apex other than using a n object to insert errors.
Can we send error messages to the user in an email from finish method.

Currently, I'm doing something like this.

```
try{
            Counter += ListtoInsert.size();
            database.insert(ListtoInsert);
        }Catch(exception e){
            system.debug('Exception Caught:'+e.getmessage());
        }
```

But I'm just debugging them. How can i send error messages to the user.

Or is there any better approach in addressing the issue.

Comment: You can send the errors in a email from the finish method. Just create a variable to gather them from your batch execute method, then format your mail and send it out in the finish method.

Comment: @JesseMilburn You probably should have added that as an answer-- that's basically what I said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly send an email to the user; in fact, this is my preferred method to avoid spamming users. You can do this by way of the Database.Stateful.

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    Exception[] errors = new Exception[0];
    public Iterable<SObject> start(...) {
        ...
    }
    public void execute(...) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch(Exception e) {
            errors.add(e);
        }
    }
    public void finish(...) {
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setSubject('Errors occurred during batch process.');
            mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            mail.setPlainTextBody(buildBodyFor(errors));
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { mail });
        }
    }
}
```

You might also include a way to send emails if too many errors have stacked up, or limit yourself to some number of exceptions (say, the first 50 or 100). Keep in mind that you do have a limited amount of memory available, so if you're concerned about having a large number of errors, consider logging them to the database and then querying them back in your finish method.

Comment: I've found I need to add a try/catch around the `Messaging.sendEmail` in this scenario as often with packages and sandboxes etc... the user running the batch can't send an outbound email. Just something to watch out for is the batch might otherwise work and then fall over in the finish method.

Answer (score 0):

Saving errors to custom object records is an excellent strategy, in general. With a persistent record in the system, other workflow can be created in response - reports, email alerts, flows, etc. It really opens up the possibilities.

Look into the `Database.RaisesPlatformEvents` interface. By simply adding that to a batchable class, you'll get a system event for any exception that occurs - even uncatchable ones. Add a trigger handler for that event to create your error log records.

Final tip - install the [Apex BOOST Library](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000IEUJvUAP&channel=recommended&tab=e) (which I wrote and maintain) and get all this for free. It provides the logging custom object & fields, a `Database.RaisesPlatformEvents` handler, as well as immediate logging - so your records will be saved even if an exception rolls back the transaction. Flow error handling and much more are in the backlog for the library. Install the [Apex BOOST Library](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000IEUJvUAP&channel=recommended&tab=e) on each of your client projects to save days of custom logging development.

Comment: You need to clearly disclose your affiliation to links that you provide, every time you provide them. While there is some information here, this feels more like an attempt to market yourself than an honest answer.

Comment: Can an answer not be "honest" *and* contain a link to a beneficial product?

Comment: Yes, it can. But not going by SFSE rules & regs lends to an air of being less than honest. From a section of the [SFSE Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion): "[I]f you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your post." (emphasis in original)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the guidance. I don't think I'm coming from a place of dishonesty, though. I've created my Apex library because I truly feel it will help developers improve their code quality and productivity. It's free. I'd like it to be a collaborative project with the community. Yes, I am trying to get some exposure for it so that developers can actually use it and benefit, but I'll be sure to disclose my affiliation from now on.